# Type conversion of custom class to float

Tags: python, casting, type-conversion

I have a class `customInt`, which looks something like this:

```
class customInt:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value=int(value)
   def __add__(self, other):
      return foo(self.value+other.value)
      # do some other stuff

obj=foo(1.23)
```

Is it possible to create an operator/attribute/property/... to cast the object `obj` to a float, so that it's possible to cast the class with `float(obj)`?

The aim of this is to create a drop-in replacement to a normal int, but without the automatic casting to a float in divisions, etc. So, **not** desired is:

- A method like `obj.to_float()`. Then it wouldn't be a drop-in replacement anymore.
- Inheritance from a castable type: In this case, I would have to overload every single operator. Which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `def __float__(self):` function in your class, and it will be called when you use `float(obj)`. You can also add `__int__`, `__str__` and `__complex__` in the same way.